# writing double quotes in python

Tags: python

I would like to write the following in a text file in the following format:

The Name is from a list of names

Item "Name" RollNo

e.g

Item "Aaron" RollNo
Item "Barry" RollNo

I am writing

```
file.write("Item" + \" + Name[i] +\")
```

but getting error

Comment: While this is an easy case to diagnose without the actual error, generally, providing the error and full stack trace can assist in helping you solve your problems.

Answer (score 29):

With double-quote strings:

```
file.write("Item \"" + Name[i] + "\" ")
```

Or with simple quotes:

```
file.write('Item "' + Name[i] + '" ')
```

Or with triple double quotes and string interpolation:

```
file.write("""Item "%s" """ % Name[i])
```

Or with simple quotes and format:

```
file.write('Item "{0}"'.format(name[i]))
```

There are many many ways to declare string literals in Python...

Comment: `file.write(f'Item "{name[i]}"')`  will also work. Take a look at the format string docs.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
s1 = 'Item "Aaron" RollNo Item "Barry" RollNo'
s2 = "Item \"Aaron\" RollNo Item \"Barry\" RollNo"
```

In python you can separate string with `'` or `"` chars, and if you use `"` you can "escape" such char in the middle of the string with `\"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the triple single quotes to have your string preserve the double quoted

str = '''Item "Aaron" RollNo Item "Barry" RollNo'''

output will be like this

[preserve the double quoted word in python string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZCln.png)