# How to print the " symbol in python

Tags: python

How do I print " symbol in python.

My code: `print(f"{filefolder}" ", uid, " f"{usergroup}" " mode, " f"{permissions}" f"{capability}" f"{contexts}")`

For example one of the outputs: `acct, uid, 0000 0000 mode, 0755 u:object_r:cgroup:s0`

But I need say, `uid` to be `"uid"`. I've tried adding the "" around uid, but I get a syntax error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [writing double quotes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308097/writing-double-quotes-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the quote mark using a backslash, use single quotes, or use a raw triple quotes:

```py
print("\"uid\"")
```

```py
print('"uid"')
```

```py
print(r""""uid"""")
```

Comment: thank you adding backslashes worked

Answer (score 2):

I think you made a bit of a mess with the string interpolation, format seems cleaner:

```
print('{filefolder}, "{uid}"'.format(filefolder=filfolder, uid=uid))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a backslash:

```
print("text: \" ")
```

gives
`text: "`